# ¿Cómo creo un package de java sin IDE?

Tags: java

Necesito crear un `package` de java tomando en cuenta que no estoy programando con ningún `IDE`, lo estoy haciendo simplemente por editores de texto.

Answer (score 1):

**Un paquete es un carpeta**, es decir, el en IDE, tiene la carpeta raíz **src**
y dentro de ella tenemos lo **paquetes**, pues bien, esos paquetes cuando se importa, pasan a ser carpetas:
Si quieres generar un paquete: **miPaquete**, debes crear:
src y dentro de ella la carpeta miPaquete, tu ruta queda ***src/miPaquete/MiClase.java***
Para compilar y ejecutar desde la consola, consultalo, ya que eso no es el tema en esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Los paquetes que creas con un `IDE` fuera de el los ves como carpetas, en el `IDE` se ve como `mx.edu.proyecto` y si vas al directorio donde creaste tu proyecto lo visualizas en carpetas `mx/edu/proyectos`, entonces puedes crear tus paquetes manualmente que son las carpetas y cuando lo importes a un `IDE` lo veras como `package`.

Comment: Para escribir la misma respuesta y solo texto, podrías haberlo puesto como comentario a mi respuesta, si añades una respuesta, que sea más completa que la mía y con mucho más detalle y ejemplos con código o imágenes... es mi opinión y es lo que yo hago.

Comment: Pueda ser que sea la misma respuesta pero con diferente explicación o forma de transmitir la información, es como cuando 2 profesores imparten la misma materia cada uno lo explica de una forma pueda ser que a uno le entiendas y a otro no pero al final es el mismo objetivo y se complementan Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente te recomiendo que utilices un IDE por las ventajas que este trae consigo. No obstante puedes hacerlo de forma manual utilizando [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

Comment: Tu respuesta no responde a lo que pregunta

Comment: Crear la estructura de directorios no es crear el paquete en si. Para crear un paquete debes compilarlo, lo que se puede realizar mediante ant.
En este link https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html un ejemplo más completo.